# Obtain movie data from MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I use `MPMoviePlayerController` to load and play a movie from a web URL. I also want to save this movie when it is done loading. However, `MPMoviePlayerController` does not have a property for accessing the downloaded data.

If I preload it I can obtain the data before passing it on to the player, but this requires that I download it first. Progressive play is obviously better.

How can I obtain the downloaded movie data?